# Using as3Crypto to encrypt/decrypt without ampersands

Tags: encryption, as3crypto

I was using as3Crypto with no probs 
http://www.zedia.net/2009/as3crypto-and-php-what-a-fun-ride/

but then I saw some special characters and I realised I could encounter ampersands.
Which is a pain because they will be inserted into a query string.
Is there a way to ensure the as3Crypto encryption does not produce ampersands?

```
public function encrypt(txt:String = ''):String
{
    var data:ByteArray = Hex.toArray(Hex.fromString(txt));      
    var pad:IPad = new PKCS5;
    var mode:ICipher = Crypto.getCipher(type, key, pad);
    pad.setBlockSize(mode.getBlockSize());
    mode.encrypt(data);
    return ''+Base64.encodeByteArray(data);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a standard [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) implementation, `Base64.encodeByteArray(data);` will not produce ampersands.

Comment: Ah, I see. Googled [this](http://www.stylusstudio.com/xmldev/200101/post70260.html)  which jives. Thanks!